# Не отображается текст в comboBox при запуске приложения

Tags: c#

[image: Скриншот[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zh6O.png)

Бесило то, что в comboBox можно было изменять текст вручную. Я решил это переключив параметр DropDownStyle в DropDownList. Но теперь текст не видно вообще, пока не совершить любое действие (выбор языка в моем случае). Как сесть одной жопой на два стула... ой, точнее как сделать так, чтобы при запуске приложения сразу был виден текст (я пытался прописывать - не помогло), и невозможно было вручную там ничего менять?

```
namespace Procent_Calculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int check = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            radioButton1.Checked = true;
            comboBox1.Text = "Українська"; // не помогло
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Українська");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Русский");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double Po;
            double r;
            double n;
            double Pn = 0.00;

            Po = Double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            r = Double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            n = Double.Parse(textBox3.Text);

            if (radioButton1.Checked == true && radioButton2.Checked == false)
            {
                Pn = Po * (1 + (r * n / 100));
            }

            if (radioButton2.Checked == true && radioButton1.Checked == false)
            {
                double Pnn = 1 + (r / 100);
                Pn = (Math.Pow(Pnn, n) * Po);
            }

            label5.Text = Pn.ToString("F2");
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.Text == "Українська")
            {
                label1.Text = "Калькулятор відсотків";
                label2.Text = "Початковий внесок";
                label3.Text = "Відсоткова щомісячна ставка";
                label4.Text = "Кількість місяців";
                button1.Text = "РОЗРАХУВАТИ";
                radioButton1.Text = "Прості відсотки";
                radioButton2.Text = "Складні відсотки";
            }

            if (comboBox1.Text == "Русский")
            {
                label1.Text = "Калькулятор процентов";
                label2.Text = "Первоначальная сумма";
                label3.Text = "Ставка начисляемого процента";
                label4.Text = "Количество месяцев";
                button1.Text = "РАССЧИТАТЬ";
                radioButton1.Text = "Простые проценты";
                radioButton2.Text = "Сложные проценты";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Прбовали после добавления данных в комбобокс `comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;`?

Comment: Ееее бой! Спасибо, все теперь работает) Щас вас отмечу, типа "ответ получен"))

Comment: добавил ответом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно просто после добавления данных в комбобокс указать на тот элемент, что должен быть выбран по умолчанию

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```